# Bash ssh for loop - env variable issue

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

When using a bash for loop and ssh'ing to multiple machines the hostname variable is not updated to be the name of the machine I've ssh'd into.

What am I missing here?

"A", "B", "C" are replaced with names of actual machines and the speech marks removed in the actual execution.

```
for node in "A" "B" "C" ;
do
    ssh $node "echo $node $HOSTNAME is alive"  ;
done
```

In the example above $node is correctly outputted but $HOSTNAME is the name of the machine which I SSH from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single-quotes:

```
for node in "A" "B" "C" ;
do
    ssh $node 'echo $HOSTNAME is alive';
done
```

If you need to pass `$node`,

```
ssh root@192.168.6.208 'echo ' $node ' $HOSTNAME is alive'
```

If you use double-quotes, then you are passing the current machine's HOSTNAME value to a remote machine.

Comment: @IanWatson, If this answer helped to solve your problem, Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows to accept the answer (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers)